# Taking a hex file and extracting data

Tags: python, parsing, hex

I basically have a file that I wish search for a specific hex value (header), once this is found, read everything from that hex value location (header) until a specific hex value (footer) is found

I have some starting code:

```
import binascii

holdhd = ""
holdft = ""
header = "03AABBCC"
footer = "FF00FFAA"

with open ('hexfile', 'rb') as file:    
    bytes = file.read()
    a = binascii.hexlify(bytes)     
    while header in a:      
        holdhd = header     
        print holdhd
```

This will print out the header I wish to find successfully (there are multiple headers in the file), however I am unsure on how to proceed with reading the file from this point and print out everything until the `footer` is found.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How large is your file? Do you need to read it to memory and convert it to hex first (as opposed to keeping it as bytes and converting your strings to bytes for search purposes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are small enough so you can load them in memory, you can treat them as regular strings, and use the `find` method (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find)) to navigate it.

Let's go to the worse case scenario: You don't have guarantee that your header will be the first thing in the file, and you might have more than one body (more than one `<header><body><footer>` block) I have created a file called `bindata.txt` with the following content:

```
ABCD000100a0AAAAAA000000000000ABCDABCD000100a0BBBBBB000000000000ABCD
```

Ok, there are two bodies, first one being `AAAAAA` and the second `BBBBBB` and some junk in the beginning, middle and end (`ABCD` before the first header, `ABCDABCD` before the second header and `ABCD` after the second footer)

Playing with the `find` method of the `str` object and the indexes, here's what I came up with:

```
header = "000100a0"
footer = "00000000000"

with open('bindata.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    print "Data: %s" % data
    header_index = data.find(header, 0)
    footer_index = data.find(footer, 0)
    if header_index >= 0 and footer_index >= header_index:
        print "Found header at %s and footer at %s" \
              % (header_index, footer_index)
        body = data[header_index + len(header): footer_index]
        while body is not None:
            print "body: %s" % body
            header_index = data.find(header,\
                                     footer_index + len(footer))
            footer_index = data.find(footer,\
                                     footer_index + len(footer) + len(header) )
            if header_index >= 0 and footer_index >= header_index:
                print "Found header at %s and footer at %s" \
                       % (header_index, footer_index)
                body = data[header_index + len(header): footer_index]
            else:
                body = None
```

That outputs:

```
Data: ABCD000100a0AAAAAA000000000000ABCDABCD000100a0BBBBBB000000000000ABCD
Found header at 4 and footer at 18
body: AAAAAA
Found header at 38 and footer at 52
body: BBBBBB
```

If your files are too big to keep in memory, I think the best is read the file byte by byte and create a couple of functions to find where the header ends and the footer starts using the file's [seek](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) and [tell](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase.tell) methods.

**EDIT:**

As per OP's request, method without having to hexlify (using raw binary) and using seek and tell:

```
import os
import binascii
import mmap

header = binascii.unhexlify("000100a0")
footer = binascii.unhexlify("0000000000")
sample = binascii.unhexlify("ABCD"
                "000100a0AAAAAA000000000000"
                "ABCDABCD"
                "000100a0BBBBBB000000000000"
                "ABCD")

# Create the sample file:
with open("sample.data", "wb") as f:
    f.write(sample)

# sample done. Now we have a REAL binary data in sample.data

with open('sample.data', 'rb') as f:
    print "Data: %s" % binascii.hexlify(f.read())
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)
    current_offset = 0
    header_index = mm.find(header, current_offset)
    footer_index = mm.find(footer, current_offset + len(header))
    if header_index >= 0 and footer_index > header_index:
        print "Found header at %s and footer at %s"\
              % (header_index, footer_index)
        mm.seek(header_index + len(header))
        body = mm.read(footer_index - mm.tell())
        while body is not None:
            print "body: %s" % binascii.hexlify(body)
            current_offset = mm.tell()
            header_index = mm.find(header, current_offset + len(footer))
            footer_index = mm.find(footer, current_offset + len(footer) + len(header))
            if header_index >= 0 and footer_index > header_index:
                print "Found header at %s and footer at %s"\
                    % (header_index, footer_index)
                mm.seek(header_index + len(header))
                body = mm.read(footer_index - mm.tell())
            else:
                body = None
```

This method produces the following output:

```
Data: abcd000100a0aaaaaa000000000000abcdabcd000100a0bbbbbb000000000000abcd
Found header at 2 and footer at 9
body: aaaaaa
Found header at 19 and footer at 26
body: bbbbbb
```

Note that I used Python's mmap module to help move through the file. Please take a look to its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html). Also, the first part of this example contains some data to create an actual binary file in `sample.data`. The execution of the chunk:

```
# Create the sample file:
with open("sample.data", "wb") as f:
    f.write(sample)
```

Produces the following (really human-readable) file:

```
borrajax@borrajax:~/Documents/Tests$ cat ./sample.data 
�������ͫ�������
```

Comment: I'll try, but seek and tell are functions to navigate a file, not to parse hex data (just a little clarification)

Comment: @InvertReality are you sure that's the correct footer? `binascii.unhexlify('00000000000')` gives the error `TypeError: Odd-length string` Its lenght is 11, which can't be unhelified (00 --> byte 1, 00 --> byte 2, 00 --> byte 3, 00 --> byte 4, 00 --> byte 5 and finally 0, which can't be made into a byte)

Comment: @InvertReality, aight, you got it, duude http://static.fjcdn.com/pictures/You_d148a6_757383.jpg

Comment: It helped me to actually practice with `mmap` as well **:-)**

Comment: I have managed to successfully do it. Thanks again! I have one little question, say I wanted to further extract something form the body, lets use your example and say I want to extract the first 2 a's in the body. Could I just use the seek method do accomplish this by using seek(2) to find the first 2 a's?

Comment: @InvertReality, Since the line `body = mm.read(footer_index - mm.tell())` already loads the body in memory, I'd just hexlify it and then `binascii.helify(body)[0:2]` (if you don't hexlify it you'll have the 2 A in the first byte so it'd be just `body[0:1]` (that would contain your As)

Comment: If this answer is what you were looking for, you can reward me by clicking on the accepted tick and giving me juicy reputation... **:-P** (your choice, of course)

Comment: Thanks! I've realized choosing answers is actually good for who asks the question. People tend to answer more to OPs that accept answers. It also gives you +2 rep. Good for everyone!! Yeeey! Thx, man... or woman... or whatever **:-)**

Answer (score 2):

Given the file size, you might want to load everything into memory (keeping data as bytes), then use a regex to extract the part between header and footer, eg:

```
import binascii
import re

header = binascii.unhexlify('000100a0')
footer = binascii.unhexlify('00000000000')

with open('hexfile', 'rb') as fin:
    raw_data = fin.read()

data = re.search('{}(.*?){}'.format(re.escape(header), re.escape(footer)), raw_data).group(1)
```

Comment: @Invert it's looking for and will capture the text between the header and footer if present (`.group(1)` retrieves this from the match object). If no such match is found then it returns `None` and you'll get the above

Comment: @Invert by 8 zeroes - do you mean eight null bytes or 8 ascii zeroes? The technique is fine - just make sure you're giving accurate data...